# Minimum time to reach from city 1 to N in less than O(N*N) time

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, dynamic-programming

There are `N` cities with cost given in array `arr[1..N]`. The time required to reach city `j` from city `i` is `|i - j| * arr[i]`.
Condition: `2 <= N <= 10^5`  and  `1 <= arr[i] <= 10^9`
Now, we have to find minimum time to reach city `N` from city `1`.

I can think of two ways to solve this problem:

One way to solve this problem is to use Dynamic Programming and calculate minimum time to reach city `j` where `2 <= j <= N`. Finally return `dp[N]`. But it will take `O(N*N)` time.

Other way is to first reach from city `1` to say city `j` where `2 <= j <= N` with minimum time then repeat same from city `j` until we reach city `N`. But this will also take `O(N*N)` time in worst case.

Is there any more optimal solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1/arr[i]` is the speed at which you leave at after stopping in city `i`.

Just start from city `1` toward city `N`, and stop in any city `i` that would increase your speed.  That is to say, stop in any city with a lower `arr[i]` than the last one you stopped at.

Comment: Very astute observation.

Answer (score 2):

Let's focus on your DP approach.

Observation: It's never optimal to go backwards.

We can solve it in O(n^2) using simple DP:

`DP(i)` - smallest cost to get to city i

`DP(1) = 0`

`DP(i) = min 1 <= j < i { DP(j) + arr[j] * (i - j)}` - you decide to go from city 1 to j somehow and then jump right to city i.

Let's change the formula a bit:

```
DP(i) = min 1 <= j < i { ( DP(j) - j * arr[j] ) + i * arr[j] }
```

We can look at it as a minimum of linear functions evaluated in specific point:

```
a_j = arr[j]
b_j = DP(j) - j * arr[j]
x = i

F_j(x) = a_j * x + b_j
```

We want to find `min 1 <= j < i { F_j(i) }`

There is a common DP optimization trick called Convex Hull Trick. It enables to solve DP problems having this kind of formula in O(n log n). You can find a tutorial here: https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/63823